# New SSD for old Asus EEE 901 netbook

Tags: laptop

I have an Asus EEE 901, one of those small netbooks that were the rage a few years ago. It's good as a travelling machine, but I'd really like to have more storage space.

This model is the Windows version with two SSDs, a 4Gb one that is a pain to get to and a 12Gb one that is easier to reach. I am thinking of replacing the 12Gb one and use the 4Gb one only to boot. I'm not sure about what kind of SSD I should be looking for - a search online brings up pages with lots of links to the old eeeusers.com forum that is now closed down.

So, let's put down some requirements: larger than 30Gb, cheaper than £40 including the cost of possible adapters, and from a reasonably well known brand. What I'm not sure about is the interface/protocol/connector I should be looking for, as it looks like there was some evolution since the old 901 came out.

Comment: About any brand-name SSD, with your budget you can easily go for those 120/128 GB ones.

Comment: @JanDorniak Sure, but what interface/protocol?

Comment: that's the hard part. I found a guide where a guy uses one specific SSD but it's the 16GB version, not the 4+12 one. Here is the link, it might help you http://www.fecj.org/extra/eeePC_901_single_16GB_SSD_upgrading_64GB.htm

Comment: http://www.jkkmobile.com/2008/07/how-to-add-more-storage-to-asus-eee-pc.html

Comment: All modern SSD are SATA.  If you have an IDE your options, are extremely limited.  The slot may not have room for the SSD and adapter.  However, if your existing SSD is SATA any SSD will work.  You may only have SATA 1 and get SATA one speed, but it will still be better.